# NEST 2.x Terms Query cannot accept 2 arguments

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How NEST 1.x expression below could be rewritten to NEST 2.x or 5.x

```
var searchResult = _elasticClient.Search<SearchResult>(
                request => request
                    .MinScore(0.7)
                    .Query(q =>
                    {
                        QueryContainer query = null;
                        query &= q.Terms<int>(t => t.Categories
                        .SelectMany(s => s.ChildCategories.Select(c => c.Id))
                        .ToArray(),
                        categories.Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c)));
```

to accept List() which contains elements on what ids elastic search query should match

```
query &= q.Terms(c => c.Field(t => t.Categories.SelectMany(s => s.ChildCategories.Select(d => d.Id))));

This line will below complain about Terms has 1 parameter, but invoked with 2
query &= q.Terms(c => c.Field(t => t.Categories.SelectMany(s => s.ChildCategories.Select(d => d.Id))), new List<int> {1});
```

UPDATE:

The last example on [elasticsearch documentation for 1.X](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/writing-queries.html) contains field and 
qff.Terms(p => p.Country, userInput.Countries) which I want to achieve in NEST 5.x or 2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take a look at the Terms query documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/terms-list-query-usage.html). A `terms` query needs a field that contains the term(s) to match and the collection of terms to match against.

field to match can be specified using `.Field()`, [which can take anything from which a `Field` can be inferred](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/field-inference.html), including a string or a Lambda expression.

values to match against can be specified using `.Terms()`, which is a collection of terms.

Given the following POCO

```
public class Project
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

A `terms` query on the tags field would be

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Project>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Terms(t => t
            .Field(f => f.Tags)
            .Terms("tag1", "tag2", "tag3")
        )
    )
);
```